# app.component overrides app-routing.module in routing

Tags: angular, routes

I am trying to create routing for my Angular 2 project. Whatever route I use, the page always loads the `app.component.ts`.

In my `app.module.ts` I have:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from "@angular/router";

import { OrderModule } from 'ngx-order-pipe';

import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { MovieSearchComponent } from "./movie_search/movie_search.component";
import { MovieAddComponent }         from "./movie_add/movie_add.component";
import { MovieDeleteComponent } from "./movie_delete/movie_delete.component";
import { A2tUiModule, Angular2TokenService} from "angular2-token";
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MovieSearchComponent,
    MovieAddComponent,
    MovieDeleteComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,
    OrderModule,
    A2tUiModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    Angular2TokenService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

My app.component.ts:

```
import { Component }            from '@angular/core';

import { AppService }           from "./app.service";
import { Movie }                from './movie';
import { MovieDeleteService }   from "./movie_delete/movie_delete.service";
import { Angular2TokenService } from "angular2-token";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    MovieDeleteService,
    Angular2TokenService
  ]
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  movies: Movie[] = [];

  constructor(
    private  appService: AppService
  ){}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.getMovies();
  }

  getMovies(){
    this.appService.getMovies()
      .subscribe((response)=>{
        this.movies = response;
      });
  }
}
```

And finally the app-routing.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import {HomeComponent} from "./home/home.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The routing does something. Because if I go to /home (which is added in the routing module) I don't get an error. But if I go to /homes I do get an error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'homes'

This is my home.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('HomeComponent')
  }

}
```

Comment: How do you navigate to other routes?

Comment: I don't. Currently I have no routes. It's all being routed to the app.component, but I don't know why.

Comment: " It's all being routed to the app.component" what is "all"? If you don't have a navigation system how do you test this stuff? By typing the url in the browser bar? And what is HomeComonent?

Comment: I mean to say, I have one functionality and that's on the app.component.ts/html. But now I want to create another route, but /home also loads the app.component.html instead of the HomeComponent. I've added a `console.log('Routing Module')` to the onInit function in app-routing.module, but that does not get loaded. So it looks like the app-routing isn't being used at all.

Comment: What does your HomeComponent look like? and where is your router-outlet tag?

Comment: Why would I need a router-outlet tag? That's just for HTML right? I'm just trying to show the html template from the home.component.ts when the /home route is being asked.

Comment: Where will the components html be placed you think? I assume you haven't read the documentation.. Your bootstrapped component needs to have a router-outlet in order for the navigation to work

Comment: The html is in the home.component.html template, which is loaded like so `templateUrl: './home.component.html',` in the home.component.ts

You are correct though ,the tutorial I was following stated I should have added `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` , but it was much later in the guide. TIL.

Comment: No what I'm saying is when you type /home, where do you think this component will appear?

Comment: I thought the home component would replace the current template with the template it's bound to. But I guess this is about the same as in AngularJS where you have placeholder element. But yea, the router-outlet places the template. Adding that fixed it.

Comment: Cool, I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your routing system to work. You need to add a `router-outlet` tag in your bootstrapped component. This way the current navigated component will be created dynamically in this tag.